# Arelle test formula

Tags: parameters, formula, xbrl, arelle

I loaded a Formula Linkbase in Arelle and want to test if the formulas are right. So I opend  the "Formula Parameters and Trace Options" (Tools -> Formula -> Parameters)
When I fill the textboxes and check the checkboxes I don't get any output in the message log. Even when I check all the checkboxes.

[image: All the checkboxes checked but still no output when pressed ok]

Does anybody know why there isn't any output of this test? Or where to find a tutorial for this?

Answer (score 1):

you should open your instance file, not Formula Linkbase.
Actually instance file must refer to entry point, which contains links to all necessary files(validations, calc, labels, etc)